# How polite is "all" as an email address?

Tags: politeness

I work in a Dutch international company, with English being the official language. I often see my colleagues starting an email with plain "all" as in:

> All,
>
> Attached the agenda for the meeting at 4 o'clock.
>
> Best regards,
>   Author

I find this "all" very rude, and think they *have* to precede it with "dear" or at least "hi". I wonder if it's just a mismatch between my (non-native) expectation and the common practice, or it's indeed impolite.

Comment: Cooperating with international workgroups (mainly Europe, but not exclusively), I don't remember having seen "All", but generally "Dear all" or occasionally  "Hi all".

Comment: Interesting! The stereotype is that Dutch people appear rude because of their brusqueness, not the other way around.  I find "All" to be abrupt, but not usually rude.  I usually use "Hello, All" or the like.  Many people avoid "Dear" because they are uncomfortable with it.  Its literal meaning implies far too much intimacy for a business context.  In fact, virtually none of my colleagues are dear to me.

Comment: @phoog, that's interesting: Do you want to say you don't use "Dear Sir or Madam" in a formal letter either? Don't break my longest standing knowledge of English usage :)

Comment: I don't generally use *Dear Sir or Madam* either, though the impersonality of *Sir or Madam* certainly cancels the intimacy of *Dear.*  I mostly prefer the plural greeting (formerly Gentlemen, now Ladies and Gentlemen) but it has been literally years since I've written such a letter.

Comment: The CEO at the last in-house job I had in publishing habitually used the similarly abrupt salutation, "Team," at the beginning of his e-mail blasts. I suppose he thought that the word encouraged a stronger sense of commitment to the cause and solidarity with the boss among people who made far less money than he did. I didn't consider the salutation rude; but I did consider it symptomatic of a rah-rah ad-guy sensibility that never meshed well with the deeply skeptical orientation of our large contingent of professional reporters and editors. I suspect that he viewed "Dear" and "Hi" as effete.

Comment: How polite? How are you measuring politeness? POB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's best to leave off any salutation unless specifically addressing one person, or group, in an email that is CC'ed to others.  If you're addressing everyone equally saying "hi all" or "all" seems as weird as if you'd started a newspaper article that way.  At best, this is folksy.

If you're not talking directly to me please don't try to pretend you are.

> ## Email Salutations for Multiple Recipients
>
> - [None]
>
> Many people don’t like to receive emails without salutations. Nonetheless, if your corporate culture supports it, sending a mass email with no greeting at all can make sense. Such an email is, after all, virtually identical in form to the traditional memo, which does not contain a greeting.
>
> - Hello,
>
> If you can’t figure out a way to address your recipients directly, whether as Marketing Staff, Colleagues, or something else, the first three salutations in this table (Greetings, Good morning, or Good afternoon) may be preferable to the more casual, less professional-sounding Hello.
>
> - Hi, all!
> - Hi, all.
> - Hi!
>
> Unless you have a very casual working environment — and even if you do — these formulations can sometimes be perceived as unprofessional. Proceed with caution.
>
> [syntaxis.com](http://syntaxis.com/book/email-etiquette/anatomy-of-an-email-message/email-salutations)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is new to me, good to know. It definitely doesn't sound weird to me, but that's why I am asking here. In Russian we would definitely start with at least something, like  very neutral and polite but impersonal "Good Day", or "Hi folks" or "Hi all" if managers are excluded. But no greeting whatsoever is impossible. Just to make sure I understand: You mean you'd just start directly the content, without any greeting at all? Even if you haven't talked to the addressees for a couple of days?

Comment: Yes, just like in this very answer. I never used your name.  That's because this answer isn't just for you.  It's for everyone who finds it.  I don't want to make them feel like they're reading your personal mail.

Comment: Correct, but this isn't an email message! An email *is* sent to specific people, and others cannot find it as they can this page. An email gets from A to B, C, D. So I would expect A to great the readers. But OK, I am learning.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this answer, please explain. Otherwise it doesn't help!

Comment: -1:  
This answer is not supported by anything but the answerer's opinion This is not a discussion forum, and people seem to have a large variety of opinions on this question. So we need an answer with references. (The other two answers also suffer from this flaw, but I am very reluctant to downvote new users.)

Comment: [This site](http://syntaxis.com/book/email-etiquette/anatomy-of-an-email-message/email-salutations) says *"Many people don’t like to receive emails without salutations. Nonetheless, if your corporate culture supports it, sending a mass email with no greeting at all can make sense."* It seems to think *"Greetings"* is much a superior salutation.

Comment: Interestingly, the linked article doesn't even mention an address without salutation. Is it the local invention?

Comment: @texnic yes it does.  That's exactly what they mean by [none].

Comment: Sorry, probably wrong wording. To me, 'none' is no address at all, while 'all' is no greeting in the address.

Comment: @texnic if I understand your meaning, it's true they don't give simply "all" as an example.  But there are several examples in [the article](http://syntaxis.com/book/email-etiquette/anatomy-of-an-email-message/email-salutations) of address with no greeting: To Whom It May Concern, Dear ..., James, Jane and Tim, Guys.

Answer (score 0):

Agree about not using "dear" in a business context. I find just "All" to be pretty abrupt; it sounds "bossy." I occasionally use "Hi all," if I need to address a group, particularly if I wish multiple people to actually respond. No greeting at all can also seem too curt, but I do this sometimes for purely lo-priority informational messages.

Comment: Welcome to ELU! This anwer is not supported by anything but your opinion. This is not a discussion forum, and people seem to have a large variety of opinions on this question. So we need an answer with supporting references.